# $X=\{1,2,\dots,10\},x\rho y\Leftrightarrow x\equiv y(mod\hspace{0.2cm}3)$

Tags: relations

$X=\{1,2,\dots,10\},x\rho y\Leftrightarrow x\equiv y(mod\hspace{0.2cm}3)$

i.e $x,y$  have the same reminder when divided by $3$ ( it was actually written in the question).

I need to find the number of elements in $\rho$

Clearly $\rho$ is a reflexive relation,symmetric,transitive.
I can see $|\rho|\ge 10$ due to reflexivity.
Thank you for helping.

options were $40,36,34,33$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=y  gives you 10 possibilities
   Since x≡y(mod3)
(x-y)/3=k  a constant.
So, x=3k+y
x=y+3 gives you 7 possibilities (using the numbers 1-10)
x=y+6 gives you 4 possibilities
x=y+9 gives you 1 possibilities
and since the relation is symmetrical
y=x+3 gives you 7 more possibilities
y=x+6 gives you 4 more
y=x+9 gives you 1 more.
This adds to 34. Those are my thoughts at this time. Hope it helps.
```

Answer (score 1):

Formally,
$$\rho\equiv\{(x,y)\in X\times X\,|\,x-y\text{ is divisible by 3}\}.$$

The elements of $\rho$ are:
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{cccc}
(1,1)&(1,4)&(1,7)&(1,10)\\
(2,2)&(2,5)&(2,8)&\\
(3,3)&(3,6)&(3,9)&\\
(4,1)&(4,4)&(4,7)&(4,10)\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
(10,1)&(10,4)&(10,7)&(10,10)
\end{array}\end{align*}
Enumerate all these elements. The answer is 34.